# Optimize Memory Usage from LINQ Query in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, query-optimization

I currently have a system where users can register and bet the scores from soccer games.
Right now i Have over 20k users, and more than 3 million bets. Every week I have to generate a ranking, so I have a query that loads on the memory all the users with bets just like this:

```
from u in context.Set<User>().include("Bets").OrderByDescending(u => u.Points)
select u
```

Where Points is the sum of the points earned from each guess.
After this query is over, I save the user and his position on another table to build my ranking.

The thing is, this query is consuming too much memory! Over 4gb!!! And I need all the users and bets to calculate the ranking.

The first alternative that I tried was: Create another table to store the user and its points. I would iterate over this query loading 500 users each time, than calculating and saving, but I am still stuck at the memory problem:

```
        int page = 0;
        int step = 500;
        while (page * step < count)
        {
            foreach (var u in context.Set<User>()
                                           .Skip(page * step)
                                           .Take(step).ToList())
            {
               //Saves in another table
            }
            page++;
        }
        //Sorts based on the data from this other table
```

Since this didn't work, I gave up and then I tried to do something like this:

```
var users = (from u in context.Set<User>().Include("Bets")
            select u).ToList();
context.Dispose()
var sortedUsers = from u in users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Points)
                  select u;
```

But didn't solve as well...

I guess the problem is about the context holding all the tracking information.
Does anyone have any clues? How to handle large amount of data using EF 4.1?

Thanks

---

Another thing that I noticed.
Let's say I have user A and user B,
Each has only 1 Bet to the same Match, I expected to have something like this:

```
User A ---> Bet 
                \
                  Match
                /
User B ---> Bet
```

But I'm having two different instances of Match having the same Data.
Is there a way to avoid this?

---

Why I am not willing to put this at a stored procedure:

The ranking is based on the guesses, and there are some rules about this sorting.

A user has N bets. Each bet associated with a Game which has a Score.

The first sorting criterion is the points. So I would need to calculate the points for every bet (each user has about 200 bets and will have about 300 by the end of the championship). That's the first join.

To calculate the points of each bet I need the final score of the match. That's another join.

After having the sum of points of each bet(which has about 10 conditionals), and sorting by it I still have to sort based on:

No. of correct bets,
No. of bets where the winner was guessed,
No. of bets where one score was guessed,
Date of the last bet,
Date of registering.

So that's a huge sort with about 6 criterions, and about 3 joins and lots of logic. To calculate this in LINQ is very trivial, and If I'd have to put this on a SP it would take a lot of time, and more error prone. (Never tried TDD and even unit testing in SPs... This ranking have tests for everything)

Comment: If you don't need to update those `User` objects, I could to suggest you to use a stored procedure to do that calculation. BTW, when you do `.ToList()`, you materialize your query and actually do retrieve all data from your database to your application memory

Comment: Its impracticable to use a stored procedure, The calculation is much more complicated than what I posted here. So I'm calculating on the memory.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Allan that this would ideally be done in a stored procedure.  If you could post the details of the calculation, maybe others could suggest ways to do it in a stored proc.

If you want to keep things as they are, there are a couple of things you could try:

1. Use [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696268%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to avoid caching:  `context.Set<User>().AsNoTracking() // etc`
2. If your `User` or `Bet` classes have a lot of properties that you don't need for the calculation, project them into anonymous types that only have the properties you need.

Hope this helps, and if you do try `AsNoTracking`, I would be curious to know how much difference it makes.

Comment: I will take a look at this AsNoTracking and will let you know. Take a look at my update on the question ;)

I was thinking if there's a way to release the memory from each user after calculating it and saving the results on the table...

Comment: The AsNoTracking gave a boost, the memory usage grew slower than before, but was still getting a OutOfMemory exception

Answer (score 1):

Dude I think it would be wiser if you just compute those data in the stored procedure and not on your C# code. No need to save this data if they can be computed by the use of existing data. Saving them in another table would cause you data redundancy and will be offending the rules of good database normalization.

Comment: I agree with you about the denormalization. I thought about this as a way of avoiding the use of memory. Most of the system's logic is these calculations. If I put everything on a SP it would be terrible to maintain so I'm trying to find a better option for now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hey buddy just read about new information this evening. try to use PLINQ it can execute multiple computations in different threads at the same time :) this can compute faster than the regular LINQ.

Comment: I thought about this, but my problem is not on the calculation, but on the storage :D I don't think there's a PLINQ to Entities, will search now...

Comment: There is buddy :) dont worry :)

Comment: PLINQ didn't help me, it was little bit faster, but the memory was still increasing.